# QTreeWidget (Applying Styles for items)

Tags: qt, qtreeview, qtreewidget, qstyle

I have a tree widget and there are three levels in the tree as follows

```
Example Tree
============================
LEVEL1
    LEVEL2
    LEVEL2
       LEVEL3
       LEVEL3
    LEVEL2
    LEVEL2
LEVEL1
```

I want to apply different styles for items, depending their levels so that I can style, LEVEL1, LEVEL2 & LEVEL3 differently. I can do this with a two level tree. Please help. I want to achieve this at CSS level (without touching the code)

I went through following documenation. I guess distinguishing between LEVEL1 & LEVEL2 is the hard part.

http://doc.qt.digia.com/main-snapshot/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qtreeview

Comment: Pure CSS has no way of distinguishing between varying levels in the tree

Comment: Is there a way to at least identify the top level items (LEVEL1 items) at CSS level ?

Comment: Nope. All items are treated equal.

Comment: Four years later ..., is there a solution yet for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This cannot be done at Qt Style-Sheet level

Answer (score 0):

I have a idea,probably not so well.
You can use the interface
QTreeWidget::setItemWidget(QTreeWidgetItem *item, int column, QWidget *widget).
Then customize your widget(Everything you want).