# QTreeView, style each level differently

Tags: c++, qt4

My problem is very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13074643/qtreewidget-applying-styles-for-items).

I have a QTreeView which is connected to a model. Is it possible to style each level of the tree in different way? I need to change background color of each line. Different level would have a different background. Expanded items would have a different color as well.

I have already tried this http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qtreeview It seems that it is not possible to do so using only css. Could [QProxyStyle](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qproxystyle.html) help? How would it be used?

Thank you, Martin.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a custom model (derived from `QAbstractItemModel` or similar), you can achieve this by returning an appropriate value from `QAbstractItemModel::data()` when data for any [appearance role](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qt.html#ItemDataRole-enum) is requested:

```
QVariant MyModel::data(const QModelIndex& index, int role) const
{
    switch(role)
    {
        case Qt::DisplayRole:
        {
            ...
            break;
        }
        case Qt::BackgroundRole:
            return QColor(Qt::red);
        case ...
    }

    return QVariant();
}
```

Using `QStandardModel` you can set data for these roles with `QStandardItem::setData()`.