# How to change the style of a branch child in a QTreeWidget?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm searching for how to change the `icon-size` of the **child** of a branch using `styleSheet`.

I couldn't find if there's a 'property' to mention it.

[image]

I'm referring to the `New Sub Item` row.

```
QTreeWidget:???? {
    qproperty-iconSize: 32px;
}
```

Comment: Did I understand correct that you want to style individual child rows? FYI: [QTreeWidget (Applying Styles for items)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13074643/7478597) If at all this probably can be achieved with a delegate (i.e. in C++) only.

Comment: @Scheff'sCat would be nice being possible to style individual child rows, but I'm referring to all children and not just one specific.